# How to change or disable the alternating background colors in Google Prettify

Tags: css, prettify

I want to change the color or even disable totally the alternating background colors in google prettify wich I use at my blog@blogger.

My current CSS is Doxy theme with this change:

```css
/* Specify class=linenums on a pre to get line numbering; line numbers themselves are the same color as punctuation */
ol.linenums { margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; color: #8B8970; } /* IE indents via margin-left */
li.L0,li.L1,li.L2,li.L3,li.L5,li.L6,li.L7,li.L8 { list-style-type: decimal !important } 
/* Alternate shading for lines */
li.L1,li.L3,li.L5,li.L7,li.L9 { }
```

This is how it looks now
[image]

I would like to change this white color to a dark grey with transparency or even completely remove the alternating color.

I've tried removing this

```css
/* Alternate shading for lines */
li.L1,li.L3,li.L5,li.L7,li.L9 { }
```

But still nothing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Succeeded in fixing this by using the background property at the

```
/* Alternate shading for lines */
li.L1,li.L3,li.L5,li.L7,li.L9 { }
```

**and also** using the `!important` keyword to overwrite the defaults.

So this is how it looks like:

```
/* Alternate shading for lines */
li.L1,li.L3,li.L5,li.L7,li.L9 { background: #color !important }
```